# How to join 2 files using a pattern

Tags: join, awk

is it possible to join these files based on first column pattern  by using awk ?

Thanks

file1

```
qwex-123d-947774-sm-shebha
qwex-123d-947774-sm-shebhb
qwex-123d-947774-sm-shebhd
qwex-23d-947774-sm-shebha
qwex-23d-947774-sm-shebhb
qwex-235d-947774-sm-shebhd
```

file2

```
qwex-235d none1
qwex-23d none2
```

output

```
qwex-23d none2 qwex-23d-947774-sm-shebha
qwex-23d none2 qwex-23d-947774-sm-shebhb
qwex-235d none1 qwex-235d-947774-sm-shebhd
```

Comment: The same way everyone else who has asked this question did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this awk one-liner should do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{for(x in a)if($0~"^"x){print x, $0;break}}' file2 file1
```

Note that, the line has risk if the lines in your file2 containing special characters, which have special meaning in regex. like `qwex$-23d`

If that is the case, `~` should not be used, instead, we should compare the string literally.

Comment: thanks. its working. but it is not printing when i have more columns in the file2. I also need the corresponding columns in the output. I should have mentioned this before. sorry. now i edited the question.

Comment: @user1883491 so the "none1"s  won't participate the matching, but you need them in output?

Comment: try this, I didn't test, but it should go. `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{for(x in a)if($0~"^"x){print a[x], $0;break}}' f2 f1`